# default font-size and relative values

Tags: css, font-size

If **font-size** is not set by developer, the default value is *medium*

So let's look at this simple code:

```html
<head>  
    <style type="text/css">

        span .medium{
            font-size: medium;
        }
        span .larger{
            font-size: larger;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="larger">Hello World!!!</span>
    <span class="medium">Hello World!!!</span>
</body>
```

And what is the result? Two strings look exactly the same.

**Why?**

Value for *font-size* is not specified explicity for element **body**, so default value *medium* should be used. Then we have two spans. *font-size* for the first one should be *larger* that body *font-size*. *font-size* for the second one is absolute, and the same like for body element. So the fist text should be *larger* than the second one. But it is not. 
Could anyone explain that to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space matters. `span .medium` != `span.medium`.

```
span.medium{
  font-size: medium;
}
span.larger{
  font-size: larger;
}
```

`span .medium` is a descendant selector, which means it's searching for an element with the class `medium` *inside* a `span`. `span.medium` means a span *with* the class `medium`.